# How to iterate through a data table by column and row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, math, iteration

I want to calculate growth for a data table.

I am stuck on iterating through the rows and columns.

DF:

```
City ...... year(2001) ... 2002 ... 2003
New York... 20.0.... 24.1 ... 28.7
Los Angeles.11.1.... 12.1 ... 13.1
```

New Table:

```
City ...... 2001 ... 2002 ... 2003
New York... nan....  0.20 ...  0.19
Los Angeles.nan....  0.10 ...   0.8
```

Code:

```py
for row in range(len(import_table)):
  for i in column_list:
    if i == "_2000":
         pass
    else:
        calculated_growth =  import_table.iloc[i].sub(import_table.iloc[i-1])
      ## update new DF ##
  column_calc_position = column_calc_position + 1
```

This is a lot harder in python than it seems. I'm teaching myself data science by re-coding something I wrote in VBA (and Excel).

Comment: Avoid iterating over rows and columns with for-loops in pandas, try to learn good pandas habits from the start. It has many convenient and powerful methods that will make your life easier, and for this problem there is a perfect example: you can just use the [`pct_change`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pct_change.html) method.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through rows:

```
for row in df.rows:
   print(row['2001'], row['2002'])
```

Iterate through column:

```
for column in df:
    print(df[column])
```